# How to create a custom tool to generate code in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, auto-generate

I simply want to **generate a class with attributes that comes from a Database table**.

If I have a Database table like the following:

```
+-------------------+
| Id | Name         |
+----+--------------+
| 1  + foo          |
| 2  + hello.world  |
| 3  + null         |
+-------------------+
```

I would like to *auto-generate* a `class` that will looks like the following:

```
class MyTable {
  public static int Foo = 1;
  public static int HelloWorld = 1;
  // null was omitted for Id = 3
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a T4 transformation to do the work. Use "Add new item" and "Text template".

The T4 language is a way to use C# code to genarate C# code. Most text is parsed directly to the output file, and new code can be written inside `<#` and `#>` tags. The file starts with wrapped imports and using statements, so a very simple template could be something like:

```
   <#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
   <#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
   <#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
   <#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>

   namespace Some.Namespace
   {
       public class TestClass 
       {
    <# 

    using(var cnn = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=ApplicationManagement"))
    {
        cnn.Open();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TextKey, TextValue FROM TblBrandingKeyValues WHERE BrandingIdentifier = 'Default'", cnn);

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var defaultText = reader.GetString(1);
            var name = reader.GetString(0);


    #>
    public string <#= name #> 
    {
        get { return "<#= defaultText #>"; } 
    }

    <#
        }
    }

     #>

    }
}
```

}
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

This template would create a class `TestClass` with a set of read only properties retrieved from database table `TblBrandingKeyValues`.

I would recommend these [T4 tutorials](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-creatating-your-first-code-generator/).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create your own custom tool you better look at the `System.CodeDom` Namespace
which contains all you need for generating code. Of course you have to code the algorithm that generate the class.

more info at the below link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404245.aspx

Bear in mind anyway that .NET already offers lots of "build-in" tool/namespace that does exactly the same job (for example using Entity Framework)

Answer (score 0):

Use [T4 Templates](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx).  I generate lots of classes that way.